# How do I get WPF control to mimic the disabled state?

Tags: c#, wpf, disabled-control

Basically I have a custom WPF button that I would like to look disabled but still be able to react to the button being pressed.

I'd prefer not to tie into other event types if possible, because there's some funny timing issues with touch and hold going on already.

Thanks!

---

This is what I wound up doing as a workaround:

```
        this.myLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGray;
        this.mySeparator.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkGray;
        this.myOtherLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGray;
```

I'm not a huge fan because it's hugely custom to the components of my custom control, but this is at least a quick programmatic way to do it until somebody has something better.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current template of a control like this:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(myButton.Template, new FileStream("c:\\bla.xml", FileMode.Append));
```

Examine the template triggers to see what changes if the button is disabled, and set the properties accordingly.

Edit: OK, that was not it... :-)

You could also set the button disabled, and then use Snoop or [Show me the templates](https://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/2091) to inspect the values of the layout properties -- or, programmatically, save them to a Style -- then enable the button again and apply the style to it?

Comment: <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"><ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding

Comment: See above.  Thanks for this answer, but the result is unfortunately bland and trigger-free.

The preference would be a something purely programmatic for future reuse.  But I could work my way through something like this.